# Pesky lil' <small> element not working with text-align, needs to be blocked

Tags: html, css, w3c, semantic-markup

So you've tried to center the `<small>` HTML element with the CSS property `text-align: center` (or `right`) and it doesn't work?

[image: small element resisting text-align]

Well, that could be because your HTML/CSS looks something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/mPqDP/3/). There's an **easy CSS solution...**

If you set a `small { display: block }` property [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/mPqDP/4/) then it works like a charm:

[image: small element being good]

Horay!

But you can probably tell something's not right... **and why does it work anyway?**

Comment: Kind of a strange way to ask/answer a question. Maybe clarify the "question" with only a question, and augment your answer with more information pertaining to the answer. IE: Don't answer and "Horay" your question.

Comment: I don't see the problem, while the question is relevant and the answer is coherent and enriches the collective knowledge. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. **Chase**, how do you mean? I thought splitting it like this was roughly down the middle — to go easy on people who find this looking for answers

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm all in favor of asking and answering questions all together. It's just a little better to simply ask the question in the question and answer it in the answer. You've kwazi answered it in your question, and then expanded on it in your answer. I'm saying, ask the question briefly, and answer it in detail in the answer.

Comment: @nicooga that's an irrelevant link. I'm not arguing against answering your own questions, just against putting the answer IN the Question.

Comment: Ah thanks for your clarification, now I get what you mean. I actually was going to do that initially, but realized that since the first CSS 'answer' is something many people would think of anyway — I thought the actual substance of the answer is in the semantics and W3 specifications and wanted to keep that seperate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, `<small>` is basically an inline element and the `text-align` property is to be [applied to block elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-align) and passed down to child inline elements (or [strings inside](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/pQk85/)).

By making `small` into a block element we are allowing the text inside it to be styled.

---

Also, the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/small.html) defines the `<small>` element to be used inside a phrasing context — similarly to elements like `<strong>`, `<b>`, `<span>`, [`<a>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968122/can-we-use-a-directly-in-the-body-or-it-should-always-in-any-block-level-tag?rq=1), [and so on](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) — which would do the [same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/mPqDP/) in this case.

[W3 wiki examples](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/small) suggest to put the `<small>` inside `<p>` tags and style that — I guess **that's the more semantic solution**, and here's [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/mPqDP/6/) if you need to see it.

---

Why is this a bit confusing?

Well, some 3rd party resources on the web don't mention it, or at least not explicitly. For example, the [HTML5 Doctor's example](http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/) uses the `small` element without a block element container around it.

Hope that clarifies things! As always, please let me know if I missed anything. (And I think I did.)

Comment: is right. You're trying to use an inline element as a block element. B/c it's not block by default, you're forcing it with "display:block". The same thing applies to <span> tags as well.